# How to move the button focus to a different section

Tags: wordpress

I am using Zerif wordpress theme. The theme is having 2 buttons namely Features and Get in Touch. [Here is the link](http://www.systroplex.com/). The first button scrolls down to features tab whixh was already there in the theme. I want the second button to scroll down to Get In Touch section but unable to do so. Here is how its going to features in customize options. What to do if I want it to move to Get In Touch section.?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to focus on id of that section to which you want to target , Please put following in option **Green button link** as per your shown image :

```
http://www.systroplex.com/#contact
```

**#contact is id of Get In Touch Section.**